# XML to ListView

Tags: c#, xml, listview, import, linq-to-xml

I have made a script in C# that should load data from a XML file into a ListView.

This is the XML file I used to test :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items>
    <wordExample languageOne="Пока" languageTwo="Doei" languageThree="Goodbye" />
    <wordExample languageOne="1" languageTwo="2" languageThree="3" />
    <wordExample languageOne="4" languageTwo="5" languageThree="6" />
    <wordExample languageOne="7" languageTwo="8" languageThree="9" />
</Items>
```

Now I get an error when I try to load the XMl into the ListView and I really don't know what it could be, this is actually the first time I try to use XML in C#.

This is the code used to load the XML into the ListView :

```
public void ImportXMLToListView(ListView listview)
{
    DialogResult dr = OPEN_FILE_DIA.ShowDialog();

    if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(OPEN_FILE_DIA.FileName);

        int counter = 0;

        foreach (var dm in doc.Descendants("Items"))
        {
            string tmpOne = dm.Attribute("languageOne").Value;
            string tmpTwo = dm.Attribute("languageTwo").Value;
            string tmpThree = dm.Attribute("languageThree").Value;

            counter++;

            ListViewItem lvi;

            lvi = new ListViewItem(tmpOne);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(tmpTwo);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(tmpThree);

            listview.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong??
This is the error I get : (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Please tell me what I do wrong I really try to understand :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`language` attributes belongs to your `wordExample` items. You need `doc.Descendants("wordExample")`

```
foreach (var dm in doc.Descendants("wordExample"))
{
    string tmpOne = (string)dm.Attribute("languageOne");
    string tmpTwo = (string)dm.Attribute("languageTwo");
    string tmpThree = (string)dm.Attribute("languageThree");
    ...
}
```

And you can use explicit cast instead of directly accessing Value property to avoid `NullReferenceException.`